# How do I add an icon within a td at the end of each row using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a 2-dimensional array.
I am using it as a source to populate an html table using angularjs ng-repeat.
I want to add an icon at the end of each row.
It works on the first two rows, but then the next several rows contain only the icon.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tblCtrl">
<table id="tableToFilter" class="w3-table-all w3-small w3-row" ng-cloak>
<tr class="w3-blue w3-mobile">
<th data-row="0" data-col="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="columns in header">{{columns}}</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr class="w3-mobile" ng-show="{{$index > 0}}" ng-repeat="rows in table">
<td data-row="{{$parent.$index}}" data-col="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="columns in rows">{{ columns }}</td>
<td><i class="material-icons editIcon">edit</i></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('tblCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.table = datags;
$scope.header = datags[0];
});
</script>
```

'datags' above is a 2-dimensional array in json.stringify format.
It does not have key/value pairs.
It is 94 rows and 9 columns. I am using css to prevent displaying columns 0,4,7,8 so that my table fits on my screen. (I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this.)

```
<style>
td[data-col="0"], th[data-col="0"] {
display: none;
}
td[data-col="4"], th[data-col="4"] {
display: none;
}
td[data-col="7"], th[data-col="7"] {
display: none;
}
td[data-col="8"], th[data-col="8"] {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

[screenshot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpom8.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share a CVM example with some data, it is easier/faster to help that way

Comment: Please provide data.

Comment: OK thank you I did figure it out.  
I think ng-repeat was perceiving the blanks as duplicates.  
I added `track by $index` and now it works.  

`<tr class="w3-mobile" ng-show="{{$index > 0}}" ng-repeat="rows in table track by $index">`
  `  <td data-row="{{$parent.$index}}" data-col="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="columns in rows track by $index">{{ columns }}</td>`
   ` <td><i class="material-icons editIcon">edit</i></td>`
`  </tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out. I think ng-repeat was perceiving the blanks as duplicates. I added `track by $index` and now it works. `<tr class="w3-mobile" ng-show="{{$index > 0}}" ng-repeat="rows in table track by $index">` `<td data-row="{{$parent.$index}}" data-col="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="columns in rows track by $index">{{ columns }}</td>` `<td><i class="material-icons editIcon">edit</i></td>` `</tr>`